# How setInterval runs asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I have a setInterval function that runs async code that calls the server:

```
setInterval(()=> {
    //run AJAX function here
}, 5000);
```

If the server doesn't get a response within 5 seconds most probably it will run set Interval again which will then make multiple requests on the same endpoint, is there a way that the setInterval only starts its next 5 second execution after the AJAX function returns a response?

Comment: no, setInterval sets an interval to run at the given intervals interval

Comment: So is there another way to do the same thing without using setInterval?

Comment: yes, a well crafted `setTimeout` - but it really depends on your actual code

Comment: As above; you’d need to do a setInterval then when you do the async call, set a flag to show you’ve done that. In subsequent setInterval calls you’d check the flag.

Comment: Can&#39;t you just wrap the Ajax call in a named function which you then call again inside the Ajax response call back using setTimeout to delay the execution?

Comment: just use [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) after the ajax response ...

Comment: You need to do this with Promises. Check into the fetch api. You can then control the entire request/response lifecycle and issue another request if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is to use setTimeout when ever you get a response

here is some pseudo code

```js
const doAjaxWithDelay = (delay)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $.ajax({
    ...
    }).done(()=>{
    // do your staff 
      doAjaxWithDelay(5000)
    })
  },delay)
}
doAjaxWithDelay(0);
```

Comment: I actually used your pseudo code and it works perfectly for my situation, though I didn't post the entire code for what this is entirely for, this answer perfectly hit the mark! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead

```
function myTimer = () => {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    //run AJAX function here
    ajaxFunc();
  }, 5000);

function ajaxFunc() {
  //case success
    //do something
  // case failure
    // do something
  // finally
    myTimer();
}

myTimer()
```